# Returning dynamically generated error response with APIs

Tags: api, security

I have a question :

Currently in my API design, if a user tries to access a resource which isn't found (404 error), we return an error message along with the resource which the user tried to access.

```
<p>&
{'errors.404.desc'}
${result?.log}</p> # 
<p>&

{'errors.404.return'}
</p>
```

But some team members have concern that this can lead to phishing.

My question is : Is it the right practice to give a dynamic error message or should this be avoided?

Comment: Could you please edit this question to give us some context or clarification? As it's currently worded, it's difficult to tell exactly what your problem is and therefore difficult to offer a viable solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Change has been made...